# How to develop modular app in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I want to know how to develop an modular app in Ruby on Rails....

Lets take an example. I am developing a project for various hospitals.
In hospitals there are various modules like billing, patient records, employee records etc.etc.

Some clients(hospitals) needs only billing but some hospitals needs all the features.

So, according to their requirements I want to  deliver only those needed features. All these features also has to be linked to each other.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. You just have to define your main application features with the authorization roles . Like , premium user can get all features where as a basic or trial user can get some other features by holding different authorization roles.

You can design role models by holding table for that or you just can make it by assigning it to the client table. Which means you have to define it with client table.

there is few gems which can make your life easier . Like :

[Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

[rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Hope This will help you to get your work done.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem which adds role management to the Rails app